# playing sound hangs on ubuntu (18.04 then 20.04 after upgrade)

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

This problem started with Ubuntu 18.04 and persists after upgrade to 20.04 (a solution I found online for similar looking problem had some people having an upgrade fix it).

The audio hangs every few seconds whether it's played on chrome browser, Ubuntu's default video player, VLC or using `aplay` from terminal, when using `aplay` when the issue happens, it shows the following error message on screen: `underrun!!! (at least 1549.585 ms long)`
Looking for the issue in aplay.c, I found it [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/alsa-utils/+/refs/heads/master/aplay/aplay.c#1330) the error seem to be `SND_PCM_STATE_XRUN` (I don't know what that is or how to fix it).

I tried restarting/reinstalling pulseaudio without success.
I also tried the solution suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/takelessons/takelessons-classroom/additional-troubleshooting/ubuntu--linux-sound-issues-in-chrome) without success.

Sound was working before just fine.

What can I do to either fix the issue or get more information towards fixing the problem?

Comment: Perhaps, try a PipeWire to see if that works for you? There's [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pipewire-debian/+archive/ubuntu/pipewire-upstream) you can try *(don't try it from the Ubuntu repos, it will be ancient, especially on 20.04. Use a PPA instead)*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems fixed for now so I will share what I did that may have fixed it (I'll update if it turns out to be not the case):

I noticed that there was a process taking too much CPU: `/sbin/modprobe nvidia-drm`

I first found a workaround to stop it:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-udevd systemd-udevd-kernel.socket systemd-udevd-control.socket
sudo systemctl start systemd-udevd systemd-udevd-kernel.socket systemd-udevd-control.socket
```

But this is just temporary solution, what fixed for me is rolling back to an older stable version of the nvidia driver, to do so open `Software & Updates` then click on `Additional Drivers` tab.

From there I selected nvidia-driver-390, instead nvidia-driver-470.

After reboot the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: So, that's interesting. Do you get any output running `lsmod | grep nvidia-drm`? If you run `modprobe nvidia-drm` manually, does it hang as well? Does killing the process work? If it does hang upon running manually, can you run a `strace modprobe nvidia-drm` and see what it's executing that takes so much CPU time?